# Python Selenium: why does map() function mess up my webelement?

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

Using Python 3.4 /Selenium have these lines:

```
get_stuff = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(stuffXpath)

get_stuff1 = list(map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('href'), get_stuff))
get_stuff2 = map(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('./img'), get_stuff)

get_stuff3 = list(map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('src'), get_stuff2))
get_stuff4 = list(map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('style'), get_stuff2))
```

Problem is get_stuff3 gives me the right list that I want,  but get_stuff4 is an empty list.

And if I switch the last two lines, then get_stuff4 gives me what I want, but now get_stuff3 is an empty list.

I've searched everywhere but no luck.

Why does map() do that to my lists?

How do I fix it?

For now I've done this to fix it but it's not elegant:

```
get_stuff2 = map(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('./img'), get_stuff)
get_stuff2a = map(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('./img'), get_stuff)

get_stuff3 = list(map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('src'), get_stuff2))
get_stuff4 = list(map(lambda x: x.get_attribute('style'), get_stuff2a))
```

Comment: Why has this question received no replies?

Comment: Still no replies.  Maybe there should be a prominent button somewhere marked "How to get replies".